# AWS hosted site does not load with IE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue while the sys admin is on medical leave. Our website loads fine on Chrome and Firefox, but with IE it doesn't load. I've checked the security group and confirmed the inbound/outbound traffic is set as follows: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

What else should I be checking?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the dev console in IE (hit F12) for client side errors?

Comment: Security groups would not cause browser-specific behavior. There are some very basic things you should be looking at. Does the IE console show any errors? Did IE work previously from this machine?  Which version of IE is this? Does it work from a different machine or different network? If you delete cookies and temporary files, does IE work? Can you live without IE until the sysadmin returns? Do you have any colleagues who understand web applications who can help diagnose?